# Firebase Analytics: See event data

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am converting my app to use the new Firebase analytics instead of the google analytics. But I am missing some key features that I use in google analytics that are just not there.

1. **First when I send an event, you can add a bundle with data. I added a bundle but where can I see the data I send? Or is this not possible with the free plan?**
2. **The second thing that I miss is the live view, is there some way to see live what's happening, or is this a feature still coming.**

Hopefully can somebody clear these things out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firebase is far superior to Google Analytics in many ways, so I would recommend you try to experiment with it a lot to get hold of how it is working and the features it is offering.

> First when I send an event, you can add a bundle with data. I added a bundle but where can I see the data I send? Or is this not possible with the free plan?

You are right, you cannot see your raw event data on the Firebase console. It just shows you the Event names, which you can use for creating Funnels (user flows, conversions) as well as different kinds of Audiences.

To see your raw event data, you will have to purchase a plan. If you have got a large user base, you better use the Blaze plan which is pay per use or else take the Flame plan. https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Once you take a plan, you will be able to see all your Events on a Google BigQuery platform where you can query data easily.

> The second thing that I miss is the live view, is there some way to see live what's happening, or is this a feature still coming.

The Events take time to get logged on the Firebase console. In my experience it varied from 2 to 6 hours. For BigQuery, I could see the Event data only after the next day i.e. close to 24 hrs delay.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the anwser :)

Comment: @Sidd : Have an official link please ?

Comment: @Farouk : I can't find an official link as of now but you can look at the pricing link in the answer which itself says a lot. Also this answer is made on my personal a well as on my colleagues experiences. Please do ask if you have any specific queries.

Comment: i cant understand this without live view how can Firebase be superior to GA ?

Comment: In GA I could get raw data for free. In Firebase I need to pay for this. How is this a better option for me?

Comment: i think need to be an easier way!

Answer (score 6):

**Update for May 2017**

1. You can now see event parameters in the Firebase console (see [announcement](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/05/whats-new-with-analytics.html)). Go to Events, click ⋮, Edit parameter reporting. The distribution of event parameters will then be visible in the dashboard for that event. Note that it's unfortunately not retroactive, so you'll have to wait for new events to be logged.
2. Firebase now has a real-time view called [StreamView](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/realtime-analytics-for-everyone.html)

Comment: 5/31/2021 - Just an update to this for anyone else who finds themselves here. You can no longer do the first step of Going to events and then editing parameter reporting.